# How to insert reactive values into a table rendered using rhandsontable based on triggers in that table?

Tags: r, shiny, observers, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

In running the code presented at the bottom of this post, a table ("hottable") is rendered on the bottom-right of the window using the rhandsontable package whereby row 2 of that table reflects the user input from the `input$choices` object in the `selectInput()` rendered immediately above it. Instead, I would like to change this whereby the "END" values from the dataframe "table1", rendered in the base Shiny table to the left, are reflected in that 2nd row of the rhandsontable “hottable” labeled "Floating reactive", as illustrated below, whereby the row from that dataframe to select "END" from is triggered by the value in row 1 of the rhandsontable labelled “Term A”. Please, any recommendations for how to do this?

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,1,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Floating reactive','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  column(6,
    sliderInput("periods","Nbr of months",min=1,max=20,value=10,step=1),
    sliderInput("beginAmt","Begin amount",min=100,max=500,value=250,step=50),
    sliderInput("npr","NPR",min=0.1,max=1,value=.3,step=0.1)
    ),
  column(6,
    sliderInput("mpr","MPR",min=0.1,max=1,value=.3,step=0.1),
    sliderInput("dft","DFT",min=0.1,max=1,value=.3,step=0.1),
    uiOutput("choices"),br(),
    ),
  br(),
  column(6,tableOutput("table1")),
  column(6,
         rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),
         fluidRow(column(1,br(),actionButton("addSeries", "Add",width = '70px')))
  )
)

server <- server <- function(input, output, session) {
  npr_vector <- reactive(rep(input$npr,input$periods))
  mpr_vector <- reactive(rep(input$mpr,input$periods))
  dft_vector <- reactive(rep(input$dft,input$periods))
  table2 <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  runOff <- reactive({
    f      <- function(x,y){x*(1+npr_vector()[y]-mpr_vector()[y]-dft_vector()[y]/12)}
    res    <- Reduce(f,seq(input$periods),init=input$beginAmt,accumulate=TRUE)
    b      <- head(res,-1)
    result <- data.frame(MO = seq(input$periods), 
                         NP = b*npr_vector(),  
                         MP = b*mpr_vector(), 
                         DFT = b*dft_vector()/12,   
                         END = res[-1]
                         )
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable(runOff())
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {table2(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(table2(),rowHeaderWidth=100,useTypes=TRUE)})
  
  observe({
    req(input$choices)
    tmpTable <- table2()
    tmpTable[2,] <- as.numeric(input$choices)
    table2(tmpTable)
  })
  
  output$choices <- 
    renderUI({
      selectInput(
        "choices", 
        label = "User selects value to reflect in row 2 of table below:",
        choices = c(1,2,3)
      )
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) 
    newCol[2,] <- as.numeric(input$choices) 
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    table2(cbind(table2(), newCol))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the modified `observe` call:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,1,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Floating reactive','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
                column(6,
                       sliderInput("periods","Nbr of months",min=1,max=20,value=10,step=1),
                       sliderInput("beginAmt","Begin amount",min=100,max=500,value=250,step=50)
                ),
                column(6,
                       sliderInput("mpr","MPR",min=0.1,max=1,value=.3,step=0.1),
                       sliderInput("dft","DFT",min=0.1,max=1,value=.3,step=0.1)
                ),
                column(12, sliderInput("npr","NPR",min=0.1,max=1,value=.3,step=0.1)),
                br(),
                column(6,tableOutput("table1")),
                column(6,
                       rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),
                       fluidRow(column(1,br(),actionButton("addSeries", "Add",width = '70px')))
                )
)

server <- server <- function(input, output, session) {
  npr_vector <- reactive(rep(input$npr,input$periods))
  mpr_vector <- reactive(rep(input$mpr,input$periods))
  dft_vector <- reactive(rep(input$dft,input$periods))
  table2 <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  runOff <- reactive({
    f      <- function(x,y){x*(1+npr_vector()[y]-mpr_vector()[y]-dft_vector()[y]/12)}
    res    <- Reduce(f,seq(input$periods),init=input$beginAmt,accumulate=TRUE)
    b      <- head(res,-1)
    result <- data.frame(MO = seq(input$periods), 
                         NP = b*npr_vector(),  
                         MP = b*mpr_vector(), 
                         DFT = b*dft_vector()/12,   
                         END = res[-1]
    )
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable(runOff())
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {table2(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(table2(),rowHeaderWidth=100,useTypes=TRUE)})
  
  observe({
    req(runOff(), table2())
    tmpTable <- table2()
    tmpTable[2,] <- runOff()$END[unlist(table2()[1,])]
    table2(tmpTable)
  })

  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) 
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    table2(cbind(table2(), newCol))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works great and looks like an easy solution. New things I learned include (a) in the req() in the observe(), you can list reactive objects (tables()); to-date I've only used req() with discrete inputs like input$xxx, I didn't know this was possible and opens up more possibilities; and (b) unlist simplifies a list structure to produce a vector which contains all the atomic components which occur in x